# Is it possible to convert list to queue in python?

Tags: python

How to convert a list to queue? So  that operations like enqueue or dequeue an be carried out.  I want to use to the list to remove the top most values and i believe it can be done using queues.

Answer (score 27):

pop from the front of a list is not very efficient as all the references in the list need to be updated.

[deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) will allow you do queue like operations efficiently

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> deque([1,2,3,4])
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: so could i make a list into queue by doing a= Queue(list1) and then use a for any further queue reference?

Comment: yes. deque is initialised with an iterable, which a list is, and support mostly all operations that a normal list would. For a complete list, see link in the answer.

Answer (score 16):

Since I was looking for an answer to this question while using `queue.Queue`, I thought I should share my findings. It is possible to convert a list into a queue using `queue.queue`.

```
import queue

l = [i for i in range(1000)]

q = queue.Queue()
[q.put(i) for i in l]

q2 = queue.Queue()
q2.queue = queue.deque(l)
```

After this code has been run, `q` and `q2` are two different queues that contain the exact same entries, but with the second method being >300 times faster on my machine.

Not related to the question, but the opposite can be done by `l = list(q.queue)` if `q` is an instance of `queue.Queue`. Hope this saves you some trouble!

This was all tested in python 3.5.2.

Comment: You should probably be using "from collections import deque" rather than queue. The queue module is mainly for used for messages in a queue used by multiple threads. While the deque is a double ended queue.

Answer (score 8):

just use `pop()`

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.pop(0)
1
>>> x
[2,3]
```

Comment: its slow, every element left need to be shifted

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list as a queue. If you want a fifo queue, just use `.append()` to add and `.pop(0)` to remove. For a lifo queue (i.e a stack), use `.append()` to add and `.pop()` to remove.

You should use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) when implementing a fifo-queue which was designed specifically for this purpose. `.pop(0)` is a O(n) operation. Using a list as a stack is just fine.

FIFO Queue:

```
In [1]: q = range(15)
In [2]: q.pop(0)
Out[2]: 0 

In [3]: q.pop(0)
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: q.pop(0)
Out[4]: 2
```

LIFO Queue:

```
In [5]: q = range(10)

In [6]: q.pop()
Out[6]: 9

In [7]: q.pop()
Out[7]: 8

In [8]: q.pop()
Out[8]: 7
```

Comment: list_.pop(0) is slow for large lists.

Comment: @dstromberg i believe it's implied in my answer.

Comment: [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) is thread-safe. lists might not be.

Answer (score 1):

collections.deque is the standard answer, though it's not abstracted terribly well.

There's also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linked_list_mod/ , if you're willing to sacrifice a little speed for better abstraction.  collections.deque is faster.  linked_list_mod lets you pass an iterable to the constructor; the provided lifo and fifo modules do not, but could trivially be modified to do so.