# how to change list to Queue?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, deque

In python3, I have used Deque(os.listdir()) and know it works.
But I have seen posts that are saying that I should use queue.Queue rather than use Deque for multi-threaded applications.

But I don't think Queue(os.listdir()) works.
Is there a clean way to do this or should I just iterate a for loop and put everything in a Queue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to convert list to queue in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639888/is-it-possible-to-convert-list-to-queue-in-python/41581928)

I think this would be an answer.
Still am not sure why Queue(os.listdir('.')) won't work.